# compiling the changes not all the document in Overleaf

Tags: pdf, compiling, overleaf

I started Latex with Texstudio and there was an option that I could compile just the changes (which leads to much faster compiling time).

Is there a similar option in Overleaf to avoid compiling the whole document every time and have faster compiling speed?

Comment: you can always use the latex `\include` mechanism with `\includeonly` to work on the chapter that you are working on

Comment: That helps to many extent. However, is there any faster way to keep the document and just add the changes similar to compile system of TexStudio?

Comment: No idea:-) (I don't use either system:-) although most likely the texstudio is doing similar to emacs and just behind the scenes copying the marked region to a new document with the same preamble as the main one, and processing that.  You could of course do that in overleaf, work on a separate project with just the section you are working on and copy that text to your main document when you want to work on a different section.

Comment: _[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]_ Sorry, this indeed isn't available on Overleaf now!